# Getting coordinates from text input in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm unable to read the correct latitude and longitude value from user query. I've added 'sys.numbers' as entities. But i'm not able to get the correct lat lng value.
When i give user input as "32.4565, 86.5564" i get the below as the parameters
number  ["32",".5564"]
PFA the attachment for my parameters configuration. 
[parameter configuration in dialogflow intent page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVimq.png)

Comment: please show the more details like user's expression and responses from dialogflow

Comment: I'm looking to get the lat lng value as parameters -> list of String to be specific. Input i gave was "32.4565, 86.5564" and the parameter value i got was ["32",".5564"]. I highlighted both the numbers '32.4565' and '86.5564' as sys.numbers

Comment: kindly attach ss link of your action , parameter and user expression in dialogflow

Comment: https://imageshack.com/a/img922/9540/7tJUQC.png

Comment: https://imageshack.com/a/img924/1417/juycCv.png
This is how my parameter is configured

Comment: You can read about parameters from the Dialogflow documentation [here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/tutorial-build-an-agent/create-intent-with-parameters) and using the client library you can see more about this from any of the [Github samples](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-temperature-converter-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

The entity sys.number can only be used with ordinal and cardinal numbers
reference - https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/system-entities

You should try using a regexp entity for this.

Comment: Please add example code to the answer. Link only answers are discouraged: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer